# Bug with misaligning the score after the svgifying operation

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

Recently MSE was svgifyied - did you notice? and I am surprised to see no thread about it, maybe create it, like it was done on MSO with its redesign?

Anyway, here is the first bug: the score in the related / linked questions in the side bar is vertically misaligned in the box (same for "Questions that may already have your answer" when asking a question):

> [image]

Comment: I need better glasses. What is mis-aligned? The box it self (it should have the same height as the line right?) and the number in it, correct?

Comment: @rene I mean that the number is misaligned with the box

Comment: So the box is OK but the number should be centered in it?

Comment: @rene yep, that's what I mean

Comment: @nicael good catch. I just pushed a fix. Should be resolved in our next production server build. Thanks.

Comment: @Kurt post an answer then. It is such a tradition for devs who fix something to post an answer about it.

Comment: *nicael, finding the most nifty bugs since '14*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@nicael good catch. I just pushed a fix. This should be resolved in our next production server build.

We have been making some updates to all of our Stack Exchange network sites. The main purposes of the updates are to normalize variables across sites and use SVG sprites for retina devices. All of this with the hope that it will be easer to launch new features (like the new profile) across the network without having to adjust the layout on all of the Q&A sites.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the CSS class `.show-votes .sidebar-linked .answer-votes, .show-votes .sidebar-related .answer-votes`. The padding on the top is `1px` while the bottom padding is `3px`. These should be the same.

Then it will look like this:

> [image]

The text itself could be centered too by the way (see the layout of the first item). That needs `vertical-alignment: middle` on `.show-votes .sidebar-related a`.

Comment: Good it works in this way; I'll reach my computer in ~2h, so I don't know the code yet :) but actually I don't know why you post this; I think devs understand how to fix this small bug :D